# Working in Switzerland. Will my german be enough?

Tags: standard-german, swiss-german

The past two three days i am searching through forums for differences and difficulties between German and Swiss German.

My situation is: I am from Greece and I want to work as physiotherapist in Switzerland (german cantons, Zurich, Zug etc). I can speak pretty good German (still learning to become even more fluent). Will I be able to find a job (i suppose it will require knowing language) and communicate with the people using German or will I need also Swiss German?

Can the Swiss German be learned easily (eg in 2-3 months) if someone speaks German good enough already?

Thanks for any answers! :)

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/for-a-foreigner-in-switzerland-how-much-practical-value-is-there-in-being-able

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to speak Swiss German, but understanding it will probably be necessary, as in my experience some Swiss refuse/or are unable to speak an understandable Swiss Standard German.

When I (German native from northern Germany with no exposure to Swiss German) went on holidays to Switzerland I several times had to switch to English to avoid a communication failure. But after 3-4 days I got used to it better.

If you are interested in diving into a dialect, I recommend the dialect from Bern, Berndeutsch, because it is a bit slower than the others.

Comment: Totally agree with: *understanding it will probably be necessary* and *Berndeutsch, because it is a bit slower than the others* +1